# Is there a way to implement this SQL query from flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, api, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I was following a tutorial for API development. The tutor was using fast API and I was using Flask. Now, I am unable to convert this SQL query in SQLAlchemy.

**I want to convert SQL query in SQL Alchemy. I am unable to figure out how to implement the Count functionality.**

My SQL Query = `SELECT *, COUNT(votes.post_id) as votes FROM posts LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id group by posts.id`

My SQL Alchemy Code: `Post.query.join(Vote, Post.id == Vote.post_id, isouter=True).group_by(Post.id)`

My Models:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default = func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False, )
    user = db.relationship("User")


class Vote(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "votes"
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("posts.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlalchemy core to implement SQL code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import select, func

select_stmt = select(Post,func.count(Post.id)).join(Vote, Post.id == Vote.id, isouter = True).group_by(Post.id)
```

Comment: Can You tell me how do I run this query? I have only worked with flask_sqlalchemy where I used .all() at the last of the query

Comment: (db.session.execute(select_stmt)).all()

Comment: It returns a tuple. [(<Post 2>, 1), (<Post 1>, 1), (<Post 3>, 1)]

Comment: You need to iterate in tuple like:   for record in "you_record": record."you_field"

Comment: The answer I get is totally messed up. different characters are added to every String. I tried to run a plain SQL command in Postgres. It gave me the answer I wanted. But from ORM, I don't know the problem, I can't get the same result

Comment: if u dont want to iterate and only get result u can immidiatly do select like this: `select_stmt = select((select(Post)),func.count(Post.id)).join(Vote, Post.id == Vote.id, isouter = True).group_by(Post.id)`